# Как сформировать SQL запрос?

Tags: sql

Есть ID реферала, нужно сформировать SQL запрос чтобы он вытаскивал по ID реферала его first_name и last_name

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: только у вас с одним id реферала несколько разных записей из какой конкретно получать имена ?

Comment: @Mike, у человека будет определенный реферал, у реферала есть ID, и нужно вывести его имя и фамилию по ID

Comment: Но у вас на картинке у 3х записей ref_id=0 значит по этому id будут найдены как раз эти 3 записи

Comment: ну и вам уже дали ответ на поставленный вопрос. если он не подходит, значит вы видимо хотите совершенно не то, о чем спрашиваете

Comment: @Mike здесь идёт выборка по id, я хочу вывести в таком ключе: https://imgur.com/a/c9QRS

т.е вывести по id реферала его имя и фамилию, но так как у каждого будет разный реферал значит и давать какой-то определенный ref_id не вариант

а сам ref_id это user_id 

mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users WHERE ref_id='$user_id'");

Comment: приведенный внизу ответ как раз достает имя и фамилию по id реферала, что в этом не так ?

Comment: @user234223 Если реферал - это человек, который пригласил нового пользователя и в вашей таблице каждая строка  - это уникальный пользователь, то в поле ref_id значения могут повторяться. А если Ваша таблица - это перечисление всех рефералов, то значения в поле ref_id повторяться не должны. И еще: если поле welcome содержит только 1 и 0, то лучше использовать булевое значение.

Comment: И я бы порекомендовал почитать что нибудь вводное по SQL, то что вы спросили это изучается за первые 15 минут в любом учебнике.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select first_name, second_name from <table_name> where ref_id = <ref_id>
```